# How to go through a queue with a loop, which includes a delay? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay, setinterval

I want to add some elements (in this case the numbers) to the queue and if a condition is true (in this case "invert"), then I want the numbers to be inverted and then added to the queue. After it I want the start() function to print the numbers in the console with a delay of 1 second. For example the numbers of the sample code should be printed like 
after 1 sec: "1", after 2 sec: "-2", after 3 sec: "-3" and when the time is equal to the queue.length then the last number should be printed, so in this case it would be the "4" after 4 seconds. Could anyone please give me a function, which can solve this problem? thanks.

```js
var queue = [];
var invert = false;

queue.push("1");
invert = true;
queue.push("2");
queue.push("3");
invert = false;
queue.push(4);

// queue should look like this
// queue = [ '1', '-2', '-3', '4' ]

var queueLenght = queue.length;
function start() {
        for(var i = 0; i < queueLenght; i++){
            console.log(queue.shift());
        }
}

start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
//generate queue
var queue = [];
var invert = false;

function addNumber(n){
  queue.push(invert?-n:n);
}

addNumber('1');
invert = true;
addNumber('2');
addNumber('3');
invert = false;
addNumber('4');

//set interval
var interval=setInterval(function(){
  if(queue.length){
    console.log(queue.shift());
  }
  else{
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},1000)
```

This generates the queue properly, creates an interval which executes code every 1000ms, then clears it once it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things, first let's go with the **number invertion**, this can be done overriding the `push` method for `queue`, like this:

```
queue.push = function(data) {
  if (invert) data = data * -1
  return Array.prototype.push.call(this, data);
}
```

If you add that code to you program you'll get this output:

> 1
>   -2
>   -3
>    4

Comment: In this way if you try to print the `queue` object, it will have also the `push` function defined inside it. It changes then the behavior for cycling inside it for example if he wants to keep only the values inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own push function and inside it play with the array.

```js
var queue = [];
var invert = false;

function myPush(value) {
  invert ? this.push(value * -1) : this.push(value);
}

Array.prototype.myPush = myPush;

queue.myPush(1);
invert = true;
queue.myPush(2);
queue.myPush(3);
invert = false;
queue.myPush(4);

console.log(queue);
```

Much more better to pass also the invert as a paramter:

```js
var queue = [];

function myPush(value, invert) {
  invert ? this.push(value * -1) : this.push(value);
}

Array.prototype.myPush = myPush;

queue.myPush(1, false);
queue.myPush(2, true);
queue.myPush(3, true);
queue.myPush(4, false);

console.log(queue);
```